# Elasticsearch, dot in value

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using ES 2.2

I have a problem with creating search (by java API). In my index I have documents:

```
public class PersonDocument {

    private String uuid;
    private String name;
    private String type;

    //setters getters
}
```

The problem is searching - I want to search all persons with matching type. My java query:

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client
    .prepareSearch("person")
    .setTypes("person")
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("type", type)))
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Some of my documents have type where value has dots in it. But when I try to search with type = `grand.parent` query is returning objects where `type` is `parent` or `grand` only.

After some tries I added `.operator(Operator.AND)`, and it returning document with both words. BUT it still isn't proper solution, because it will return documents with type `parent.grand`.

How to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**

Here is mapping from curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/person/_mapping/?pretty'

```
{
  "person" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "person" : {
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "type" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "uuid" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your field type is text and it would be analyzed into `grand` and `parent`. depending on your use case you can set the parameter type to keyword or if you want to do full text search, you should define custom tokenizer which tokenizes on space for say.
It's good to have your index `mapping` and `settings`.

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Comment: Run the following command: `curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_mapping/?pretty'
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_all/_mapping/?pretty'` and provide the result

Comment: Can you help now?